# Is there a purpose to an empty column in Cucumber?

Tags: testing, cucumber, cypress

I've inherited a codebase to refactor etc with the original devs being unavailable for the time being.

In the Cucumber/Cypress tests I have noticed that there is an empty column used throughout the `.feature` files. I'm just wondering if there is any reason/purpose for this, or whether it is a mistake that has been copy/pasted when creating new features?

I have not seen anything like this in the official docs, but maybe I've not been looking hard enough?

For example:

```
Scenario Outline: Does something
    Given User accessed site on <device>
    When User logs in with their <username> and <password>
    Then They should see <scenario>

    Examples:
      |  device    | |     username    | password | scenario          |
      |  "desktop" | |  "someusername" | "abc123" | "should-login"    |
```

You can see the empty column between `device` and `username`.

Comment: It's irrelevant and maybe a mistake in your original codebase. Cucumber does not require an empty column, and it might cause confusion or unexpected behavior.

Comment: @mandy8055 that was my initial instinct! I shall trial getting it removed to see if anything changes... Once I can get the tests actually running, that is XD